Movie about an American infiltrator in an Islamic terror group
I saw this movie several years ago, maybe about halfway between 9/11 and today, but it was on video so I couldn't say exactly when it was made.
The protagonist was an American agent (CIA?) working in an Islamic terrorist cell, who had to walk a fine line between gaining the terrorists' trust, minimizing actual damage and civilian casualties, and not being discovered.  I remember there were discussions about their ideology and motivations, and the concept of Muslims being allowed to lie about their faith was brought up at one point, with the protagonist having a different interpretation of it than the terrorists.
In the end, he got put in charge of planning a major attack on American soil, with dozens of suicide bombers designated to hit various targets in the USA, all at about the same time.  He ended up handling it via the darkly humorous solution of assigning all of them (without telling any of them that this was the case) to bomb the same Greyhound bus, so that in the end everyone on the bus, including the driver, was a suicide bomber, and the only damage that was done, aside from the loss of the terrorists' lives, was the bus being destroyed.
Does anyone know what movie this was?

Traitor from 2008 with Don Cheadle.

Samir Horn is a former soldier, a devout Muslim, and U.S. citizen in the Middle East selling bomb detonators to Islamic radicals. He joins their cause as both the FBI and a rogue CIA agent track him. Horn escapes a Yemeni prison, goes underground in France where he proves his abilities, and is sent to the United States to choreograph a simultaneous and multiple terror attack. Will the intelligence agencies talk to each other, and can Horn be stopped? 

His solution is the one you described: He puts all the terrorists on the same bus. Here's the trailer:



